# Trying to add an image as a background to c++ GUI but wxWidgets says file cannot be found

Tags: c++

I'm trying to make a simple C++ wxWidgets GUI with some buttons, sliders, etc and wanted to add a background image to replace the plain white background, but have returned with an error stating that the file specified cannot be found.

```
#include "MainFrame.h"
#include <wx/wx.h>

MainFrame::MainFrame(const wxString& title): wxFrame(nullptr, wxID_ANY, title) {
    wxPanel* panel = new wxPanel(this);

    wxButton* button = new wxButton(panel, wxID_ANY, "Button", wxPoint(150, 50), wxSize(100, 35));

    wxCheckBox* checkBox = new wxCheckBox(panel, wxID_ANY, "Check Box", wxPoint(320, 60));

    wxStaticText* staticText = new wxStaticText(panel, wxID_ANY, "StaticText - NOT editable");



    wxPNGHandler* handler = new wxPNGHandler;

    wxImage::AddHandler(handler);

    wxStaticBitmap* image;

    image = new wxStaticBitmap(panel, wxID_ANY, wxBitmap("GALAXY_FOTO.png", wxBITMAP_TYPE_PNG), wxPoint(50, 100), wxSize(100, 500));

}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s6HBB.png)

Any ideas on how to fix?

Comment: When you use a relative path as you have it is relative to the current working directory of the program. That may not be, and because of the error probably isn't, where you think it is. Try an absolute path to rule that problem out. If that works then you'll need to figure out where the working directory is and perhaps how to change it. Details on how you are running your program would help diagnose that.

Comment: Try specifying the full path to the image; if that makes it work, it means your current directory isn't what you think it is.

Comment: How would i specify the absolute path?

Comment: Depends on your operating system. `c:/some/directory/to/file.bmp` on Windows.

Comment: im pretty new to all of this, where can i find my current working directory and then specify it for the gui?